# How to update two arrays in the same request within the updateDoc function of firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m having a problem updating two arrays within the `updateDoc` function of firestore. To put them in context, I’m doing a simple task application in react and I’m storing the data in firebase, within my app I have a small function to mark a task as performed, which when executed is removed from a to-do array and added to a completed task array.

At first I was doing this:

```
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid)

  const markDone = async task => {
    setIsReading(true)
    const { updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } = await import('firebase/firestore')
    if (task.done === false) {
        await updateDoc(docRef, { 'listOfTask.pending': arrayRemove(task)})
        task.done = !task.done
        await updateDoc(docRef, { 'listOfTask.performed': arrayUnion(task)})
    } else {
        await updateDoc(docRef, { 'listOfTask.performed': arrayRemove(task) })
        task.done = !task.done
        await updateDoc(docRef, { 'listOfTask.pending': arrayUnion(task) })
    }
    await readData()
  }
```

this is the structure:

[image]

pending just like performed contains an array to store tasks as they are marked solved or not, in the image we see a solved task and a pending

I basically worked well, I removed the task from one array and put it in the other, but I wanted to improve this so I modified the `markDone()` function to avoid calling the `updateDoc` function twice and spending resources on it, so I left it like this:

```
  const markDone = async task => {
    setIsReading(true)
    const { updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } = await import('firebase/firestore')
    const t = task                 //Clone the task object
    if (task.done === false) {
      t.done = !t.done             //Change value to true in done property in cloned task
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        'listOfTask.pending': arrayRemove(task), //Remove original task in pending
        'listOfTask.performed': arrayUnion(t)    //Add cloned task in performed 
      })
    } else {
      t.done = !t.done
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        'listOfTask.pending': arrayUnion(task),
        'listOfTask.performed': arrayRemove(t)
      })
    }
    await readData()
  }
```

The problem that is emerging is that doing it this way, passes the task of the pending arrangement to the performed arrangement but is not removed from the pending arrangement, I do not know if I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in JavaScript:

```js
    const t = task;                 //Clone the task object
```

will NOT clone the object.  It has `t` and `task` point to the exact same object.  And when you update `t.done`, then `task.done` will also change (since they both point to the same object).

There are a few ways to clone objects in JavaScript.  The simplest way is:

```js
    const t = {...task};            //Clone the task object
```

though that only does a "shallow clone".

One of the more popular ways to get a "deep clone" in JavaScript is to use the `lodash` library.

I suspect the reason that you are not able to remove the `task` is because it is no longer an identical match of the object in the array...because you have modified its `.done` value.  Properly cloning `task` should resolve the issue for you.

---

Reproduction of the "not cloned" issue using the `node` command

```
$ node                   

> let task = {done: true, name: 'fred'}
> let t = task
> t
{ done: true, name: 'fred' }
> t.done = !t.done
false
> t
{ done: false, name: 'fred' }
> task
{ done: false, name: 'fred' }
> t === task
true
> let t2 = {...task}
> t2 === task
false
> t2
{ done: false, name: 'fred' }
> task
{ done: false, name: 'fred' }
```